# finding result of multiplication in ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

[image]

So i have the ring R ={a,b,c,d}. And i should find the elements in the dots and find the ideals of R.
and what i get is that ab=d, ba=b,bb=d,bc=b,cb=d. Bur in this case i get 2 unit elements? Any tips  if i've done something wrong ?

Comment: What do you mean by "unit zero elements"? Obviously $d$ is the additive neutral element of the group $(R,+)$. How do you find $ab=d$?

Comment: i meen 2 unit elements

Comment: What you have done looks wrong to me. Looking at the first row we see that $a$ can't be a unit ($ac=a$). $d$ is clearly not a unit (e.g .$ad=d$). Look at the third row what does it tell you about $c$? Which element must be a unit?

Answer (score 0):

The $0$ of the ring is $d$.

The elements $a$ and $c$ are idempotents; moreover $a+c=b$, so
$$
ba=(a+c)a=a^2+ca=a+c=b
$$
Similarly, $ab=a(a+c)=a^2+ac=a+a=d$. Also
$$
cb=c(a+c)=ca+c^2=c+c=d
$$
and $bc=(a+c)c=ac+c^2=a+c=b$. Finally,
$$
b^2=(a+c)(a+c)=a^2+ac+ca+c^2=a+a+c+c=d
$$
Your computations are good.

Now the multiplication table reads
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
& a & b & c & d \\
\hline
a & a & d & a & d \\
b & b & d & b & d \\
c & c & d & c & d \\
d & d & d & d & d
\end{array}
$$
Assuming this gives a ring (one has to check that associativity and distributivity hold), it has just two right identities, namely $a$ and $c$, which are not a left identities.

An ideal must be an additive subgroup to begin with. Since we have four elements, the additive subgroups can have order $1$, $2$ or $4$. The nontrivial case is $2$.

The additive subgroups of order $2$ are
$$
\{d,a\} \qquad \{d,b\} \qquad \{d,c\}
$$
Can you finish?

Comment: ab=a(a+c)=a2+ac=a+c=bab=a(a+c)=a2+ac=a+c=b.
Look a*c isn't c it's a...

Comment: and in your calculations for b*a , c*a  is not equal to a..

Comment: @SimonJachson Should be fixed